# Update Value in Mongo 3.6.0 while updating value inside json object

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongo

I want to update `FieldA` in `someFields` while `someFields` is `null` in MongoDB

```
{ 
  "someFileds : {
      "FieldA" : "ABS"
  }
}
```

`someFields` may have more fields as well but Just want to ensure that other fields won't be overridden.

Sometime `SomeFields` won't be having any fields so want to

I am using below code for set the the value however value for `someFields` is `null` in MongoDB.

```
BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();

dbObject.put("SomeFields.FieldA", "TEST");
```

Could you please suggest how can handle the `null` in this scenario.

Comment: Just to be sure... you save your doc after that?

Comment: Yes.. I am saving the document. My Problem is that in some use cases SomeFields will have some fields with values and some use cases it wouldn't have any value.
Use Case First :
Value in DB :
SomeFields: {

}

Answer (score 0):

Use this **Mongo update** query.

```
db.collection.update({}, {$set:{"someFields": {"FieldA": "Test"}}});
```

It will create FieldA in someFields when it is null otherwise will only update FieldA.

In your case kindly pass object all time in 2nd parameter of put.

```
dbObject.put("SomeFields", {FieldA:"TEST"});
```

Comment: Actually it works fine when someFields already has some value in mongo db but in case if it doesn't have any value then it throws null pointer exception.

Comment: I tried the query what I told to you it works fine for me.